# Simple inequality true?

Tags: inequality

For positive numbers $a,b,c,d$, is it true that $\frac{a+b}{c+d} \leq \max\{\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{d}\}$?  This question seems quite silly but I'm having a complete brain freeze..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k = \max\left\{\dfrac{a}c, \dfrac{b}d\right\}$. Since $a,b,c,d>0$, we have $a\leq ck$ and $b \leq dk$. Hence,
$$\dfrac{a+b}{c+d} \leq \dfrac{ck+dk}{c+d} = k = \max\left\{\dfrac{a}c, \dfrac{b}d \right\}$$

Comment: Yup. Thanks ${}{}{}$

Comment: This is a really slick trick! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

It's just an weighted average. $\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{c}c+\dfrac{b}{d}d}{c+d}$

Answer (score 1):

Using Contradiction, if it's not true, then $\frac{a+b}{c+d}>\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{d}$. Now cross multiplication gives $bc>ad$ and $ad>bc$ which is impossible.

Comment: I don't think this argument works, since if it's not true, we need only have that one of $\frac{a+b}{c+d} > \frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{a+b}{c+d} > \frac{b}{d}$ is true.

Comment: No. If the statement is not true, then $\frac{a+b}{c+d}>\max\{\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{d}\}$. So it's larger than both of them.

Comment: Right.  Thanks also.